# Can not execute controller test with @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing, startup

I have a Spring Boot application. Version is `2.3.1`.

Main Application looks like:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@SpringBootApplication
public class LocalServiceApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    private final DataService dataService;
    private final QrReaderServer qrReaderServer;
    private final MonitoringService monitoringService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        dataService.fetchData();
        monitoringService.launchMonitoring();
        qrReaderServer.launchServer();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LocalServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

After the application is started I have to execute 3 distinct steps which have done with `CommandLineRunner`:

- first gets remote data and store it locally (for test profile this step is skipped)
- start async folder monitoring for file uploads with [WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).
- launch TCP server

I have a controller like:

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/v1/permissions")
public class CarParkController {
    private final PermissionService permissionService;

    @PostMapping
    public CarParkPermission createPermission(@RequestBody @Valid CarParkPermission permission) {
        return permissionService.createPermission(permission);
    }
}
```

Ant test with Junit 5 looks like:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class CarParkControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private PermissionService permissionService;
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Test
    void testCreatingNewPermissionSuccess() throws Exception {
        CarParkPermission permission = CarParkPermission.builder()
                .id(56)
                .permissionCode("1234")
                .build();

        when(permissionService.createPermission(refEq(permission))).thenReturn(permission);

        postPermission(permission).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    private <T> ResultActions postPermission(T instance) throws Exception {
        return this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/permissions")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(gson.toJson(instance)));
    }
}
```

Looks like it should work fine.

However, the test isn't executed:

```
2020-08-27 14:42:30.308  INFO 21800 --- [           main] c.s.i.CarParkControllerIntegrationTest   : Started CarParkControllerIntegrationTest in 8.593 seconds (JVM running for 10.03)
2020-08-27 14:42:30.334  INFO 21800 --- [           main] c.s.s.s.DataServiceTestImpl     : Fetch data for test profile is skipped
2020-08-27 14:42:30.336 DEBUG 21800 --- [   carpark-ex-1] c.s.monitoring.MonitoringServiceImpl     : START_MONITORING Results from Cameras for folder: D:\results-from-camera
2020-08-27 14:42:30.751 DEBUG 21800 --- [           main] c.s.netty.TCPServer              : TCP Server is STARTED : port 9090
```

After those lines execution hangs up forever.

**UPDATE**

Here are details for monitoring task:

```
@Async
@Override
public void launchMonitoring() {
    log.debug("START_MONITORING Results from Cameras for folder: {}", properties.getFolder());
    try {
        WatchKey key;
        while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {

                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    log.info("FILE_CREATED: {}", event.context());
                    // processing resource

                    deleteResource(zipFullPath);
                } else if (kind == ENTRY_DELETE) {
                    log.info("RESOURCE_DELETED: {}", event.context());
                }
            }
            key.reset();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("interrupted exception for monitoring service", e);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } 
}
```

Also `AsyncConfiguration` is configured with TaskExecutor.

Launch method from TCPServer looks:

```
@Override
public void launchServer() {
    try {
        ChannelFuture serverChannelFuture = serverBootstrap.bind(hostAddress).sync();
        log.debug("TCP Server is STARTED : port {}", hostAddress.getPort());

        serverChannel = serverChannelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync().channel();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        shutdownQuietly();
    }
}
```

***How to solve this issue?***

Comment: Because you are starting threads monitoring stuff, it will not continue to start. Basically your `CommandLineRunner` hangs forever.

Comment: @M.Deinum updated question with 2 running methods for `test` profile. Does any solution or workaround exist for such case?

Comment: There is no `@EnableAsync` so the `@Async` doesn't do a thing. Also you are starting a tcp server which is blocking. Even with an `@Async` it might (and probably will not) work due to early init of the beans due to injecting them into the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class through a constructor.

Comment: @M.Deinum `EnableAsync` is enabled. And it works fine. Before coming up to this decision only the first bean was executed. It is exactly at separate configuration `AsyncConfiguration` with `taskScheduler` and `getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` implementations.

Comment: The starting of the server is blocking (as mentioned before) and thus the tomcat initializing never finishes and thus your test will never be started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have understood that execution is blocked (thanks to [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)).

So changed the last method for:

```
@Async
@Override
public void launchServer() { 
    // ...
}
```

And shifted to `ObjectMapper` instead of `Gson` for converting instance to **JSON** format:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class CarParkControllerIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Test
    void testCreatingNewPermissionSuccess() throws Exception {
        CarParkPermission permission = CarParkPermission.builder()
                .id(444)
                .permissionCode("1234")
                .build();
        postPermission(permission).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    private <T> ResultActions postPermission(T instance) throws Exception {
        return this.mockMvc.perform(post("/v1/permissions")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(instance)));
    }
}
```

And finally, it works fine.